# Spark2 shell exits with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED` error

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

Spark shell fails to startup. We are using cloudera cdh 5.14.2 with java 1.8.0_91. We are not sure which jar files are having problems unzipping.

```
$ spark2-shell --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0.cloudera1
  /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_91
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user jenkins on 2017-07-13T00:28:58Z
Revision 39f5a2b89d29d5d420d88ce15c8c55e2b45aeb2e
Url git://github.mtv.cloudera.com/CDH/spark.git
Type --help for more information.
```

*Spark shell doesnt start*

> > $ spark2-shell
> >         SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
> >         SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> >         SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> >         SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> >         SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
> >         SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
> >         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
> >             at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:58)
> >             at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:566)
> >             at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(ZipFile.java:60)
> >             at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.next(ZipFile.java:524)
> >             at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:499)
> >             at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:480)
> >             at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.x$1$lzycompute(ZipArchive.scala:135)
> >             at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.x$1(ZipArchive.scala:123)
> >             at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.root$lzycompute(ZipArchive.scala:123)
> >             at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.root(ZipArchive.scala:123)
> >             at scala.reflect.io.FileZipArchive.iterator(ZipArchive.scala:152)
> >             at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
> >             at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.foreach(AbstractFile.scala:91)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.traverse(ClassPath.scala:277)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.x$15$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:299)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.x$15(ClassPath.scala:299)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:299)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:299)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:264)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath$$anonfun$packages$1.apply(ClassPath.scala:358)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath$$anonfun$packages$1.apply(ClassPath.scala:358)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
> >             at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
> >             at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
> >             at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath.packages$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:358)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:353)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:269)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
> >             at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:211)
> >             at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
> >             at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.init(Mirrors.scala:256)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror$lzycompute(Global.scala:73)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:71)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:39)
> >             at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
> >             at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
> >             at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1394)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.(Global.scala:1215)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$IMain$$_initialize(IMain.scala:132)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.global$lzycompute(IMain.scala:161)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.global(IMain.scala:160)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:680)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
> >             at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
> >             at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
> >             at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
> >             at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
> >             at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:98)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
> >             at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
> >             at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
> >             at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:70)
> >             at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:53)
> >             at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> >             at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
> >             at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
> >             at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
> >             at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
> >             at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be due to an incompatible scala library

Comment: Thanks Chitral! Spark documentation say Spark 2.0 is built with Scala 2.11 by default. Ref: http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html Do you recommend installing different version of Scala ? We Also do you recommend installing Scala separately ? Thanks

Comment: yes spark 2 is built with scala, you do not need to install anything extra.